# How can I hide the legend?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, charts

I want to make a smooth and nice graph with no legend as it explains itself (the graph that is).

How can I hide it? I've tried the same approach as to making the plotarea transparent:

```
                    <charting:Chart.PlotAreaStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="Grid">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                        </Style>
                    </charting:Chart.PlotAreaStyle>
```

How can I hide the legend, in the same manner some way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found that I could hide the chart legend by setting the chart's `LegendStyle` to a `Style` such as the following:

```
        <charting:Chart.LegendStyle>
            <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="0" />
            </Style>
        </charting:Chart.LegendStyle>
```

Oddly enough, setting the `Visibility` to `Collapsed` doesn't work - the legend still appears at runtime.

Comment: It works very well, and thanks for pointing out FrameworkElement. You can use <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />